# What happens if I disable a mod in an already generated world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Specifically, I have XyCraft enabled as part of ftb ultimate but I get loads of these drops but looking at the current usage, I can't see me needing them.

If I disable the mod what happens to:

1 The items I have already collected that come from that mod?

and

2 Ore that has been generated in my world underground from that mod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items you have collected will disappear from your inventory, and ores that have been generated will be filled with air blocks.

Answer (score 0):

if you install a new mod afterwards then it can claim the old ids of the old mod and then then the old blocks and items (that never got overwritten because the chunk didn't load in the mean time) will become the new ones

but if both mods use NBT data on those blocks or items then you might get crashes because the format doesn't match up